# XamlWindow cannot be found?

Tags: uwp, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to write some coded UI tests for a UWP app.

The problem is that my test seems to not be able to find any xaml elements, simply throwing `UITestControlNotFoundException`.

The code below successfully launches my app, but as soon as I try to access most of the `XamlWindow` properties I get an `UITestControlNotFoundException`:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{ 
    XamlWindow appWindow = XamlWindow.Launch("ba5e2113-dece-4009-ac42-f285078e995a_egav42bnkxfp2!App");
    var children = appWindow.GetChildren(); // UITestControlNotFoundException
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar issue but was told simply that Coded UI was no longer being maintained for Store apps going forward from Windows 8.1. Unfortunately, I had to look into Appium as an alternative.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that.  I'm looking at [Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) as an alternative.